# Smoothing the pixels of an enlarged image

Tags: python, image, image-processing, pixel, smoothing

I'm very new to programming, trying to learn Python. I am trying to smooth the pixels of an image by taking an average of each pixel and its neighbors. I was able to run the following successfully.

```
from cImage import *
import statistics as s


def smoothImg(oldimage):
    theWindow = ImageWin("Smooth Image",1200,1200)
    theImage = FileImage(oldimage)
    theImage.draw(theWindow)

    height = theImage.getHeight()
    width = theImage.getWidth()

    newImage = EmptyImage(width,height)

    for row in range(height):
        for col in range(width):
            try:
                pixelVal = theImage.getPixel(col-1,row-1)
            except:
                pixelVal = theImage.getPixel(col,row)  #maybe change to "pass"
            try:
                pixelVal2 = theImage.getPixel(col-1,row)
            except:
                pixelVal2 = theImage.getPixel(col,row)
            try:
                pixelVal3 = theImage.getPixel(col-1,row+1)
            except:
                pixelVal3 = theImage.getPixel(col,row)
            try:
                pixelVal4 = theImage.getPixel(col,row-1)
            except:
                pixelVal4 = theImage.getPixel(col,row)
            pixelVal5 = theImage.getPixel(col,row)
            try:
                pixelVal6 = theImage.getPixel(col,row+1)
            except:
                pixelVal6 = theImage.getPixel(col,row)
            try:
                pixelVal7 = theImage.getPixel(col+1,row-1)
            except:
                pixelVal7 = theImage.getPixel(col,row)
            try:
                pixelVal8 = theImage.getPixel(col+1,row+1)
            except:
                pixelVal8 = theImage.getPixel(col,row)
            try:
                pixelVal9 = theImage.getPixel(col+1,row)
            except:
                pixelVal9 = theImage.getPixel(col,row)

            redMean = s.mean([pixelVal[0],pixelVal2[0],pixelVal3[0],pixelVal4[0],pixelVal5[0],pixelVal6[0],pixelVal7[0],pixelVal8[0],pixelVal9[0]])
            greenMean = s.mean([pixelVal[1],pixelVal2[1],pixelVal3[1],pixelVal4[1],pixelVal5[1],pixelVal6[1],pixelVal7[1],pixelVal8[1],pixelVal9[1]])
            blueMean = s.mean([pixelVal[2],pixelVal2[2],pixelVal3[2],pixelVal4[2],pixelVal5[2],pixelVal6[2],pixelVal7[2],pixelVal8[2],pixelVal9[2]])

            meanPixel = Pixel(redMean,greenMean,blueMean)
            newImage.setPixel(col,row,meanPixel)


    newImage.setPosition(width+1,0)
    newImage.draw(theWindow)

    theWindow.exitOnClick()
    return
```

The program seems to work, but I can't imagine that this is the best way to do it. Also I'd like to be able to take a wider average of pixels instead of just an immediate neighbor. I tried running this function within my for loops but it just gave me a completely gray image.

```
def getMean(numPixels,image):
        pixelVals = []
        for row in range(numPixels):
            for col in range(numPixels):
                pixelVal = image.getPixel(col,row)
                pixelVals.append(pixelVal)
        redMean = int(s.mean([p[0] for p in pixelVals]))
        greenMean = int(s.mean([p[1] for p in pixelVals]))
        blueMean = int(s.mean([p[2] for p in pixelVals]))
        meanPixel = Pixel(redMean,greenMean,blueMean)
        return meanPixel
```

This problem is taken from "Python Programming in Context". Exercise 6.25 on page 222.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Rather than call `getPixel()` to obtain values from the image one pixel at a time, you could use `Image.getdata()` to get a image data sequence object and then convert that into a normal Python list object. That would allow you access the pixel value via simple indexing operations much more quickly.

Comment: From a quick look at your code, you are doing a convolution with 3x3 kernel of ones and scaling by 1/9. Try Googling `convolution python image processing`